# Javascript/Jquery on click anchor tag addClass to specific LI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For example, I would like to add class '`active`' to `LI` that have class' `list-1`' when user clicks anchor tag which have class '`link-1`' and remove class '`active`' from other lists. Same case applies further. 
Any suggestion would be very helpful.

```
<br>
<br>
<ul class="list-item">
    <li class="list-0 active">Product One</li>
    <li class="list-1">Product Two</li>
    <li class="list-2">Product Three</li>
    <li class="list-3">Product Four</li>
</ul>`
<br>
<br> `
<div class="pager-list">
    <a href="#" class="link-0">1</a>
    <a href="#" class="link-1">2</a>
    <a href="#" class="link-2">3</a>
    <a href="#" class="link-3">4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: My suggestion is to Google for an answer to the part(s) that you don't know how to do. People ask about this sort of thing all the time, so I think you'll have no trouble learning how if you search.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```js
$(".pager-list").find("a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var value = $(this).data("value");
    $(".list-item")
        .find(".list-" + value).addClass("active")
        .siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

```html
<ul class="list-item">
    <li class="list-1 active">Product One</li>
    <li class="list-2">Product Two</li>
    <li class="list-3">Product Three</li>
    <li class="list-4">Product Four</li>
</ul>
<div class="pager-list">
    <a href="#" data-value="1">1</a>
    <a href="#" data-value="2">2</a>
    <a href="#" data-value="3">3</a>
    <a href="#" data-value="4">4</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="list-item">
     <li class="list-0 active">Product One</li>
     <li class="list-1">Product Two</li>
     <li class="list-2">Product Three</li>
     <li class="list-3">Product Four</li>
 </ul> 

<div class="pager-list">
  <a href="#" class="link-0" data-rel="list-0">1</a>
  <a href="#" class="link-1" data-rel="list-1">2</a>
  <a href="#" class="link-2" data-rel="list-2">3</a>
  <a href="#" class="link-3" data-rel="list-3">4</a>
</div>



<script>
$('.pager-list').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.list-item li').removeClass('active');
    $('.list-item li.'+$(this).data('rel')).addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

or alternatively (without data-, but then order of the links and order of the list items is important)

```
<ul class="list-item">
     <li class="list-0 active">Product One</li>
     <li class="list-1">Product Two</li>
     <li class="list-2">Product Three</li>
     <li class="list-3">Product Four</li>
 </ul> 

<div class="pager-list">
  <a href="#" class="link-0">1</a>
  <a href="#" class="link-1">2</a>
  <a href="#" class="link-2">3</a>
  <a href="#" class="link-3">4</a>
</div>

<script>
    $('.pager-list').on('click', 'a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var links = $('.pager-list a');
        $('.list-item li').removeClass('active'); 
        $('.list-item li').eq(links.index(this)).addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why duplicate the class in a `data-` attribute?

Comment: class is `link-X` and data is `list-X`

Comment: sure, but lots of duplication there. All you need is the number, and you've already got that.

Comment: I agree, it depends of what you need